Automating additional text to slide show as it is emailed in to a specific address or site?
This is a bit weird but I have seen this done before when I was at a presentation in the early-ish days of Twitter, and I have seen something like it here and there...
The situation: I want to have a slide show that shows text from incoming emails and automatically updates. At the presentation I mentioned above I recall that there was one that showed the relevant Twitter messages as they came in (they were not always hashtagged then, this was about eight years ago?).
What we are doing is a memorial service, and I wanted to have something like one of those books people sign in to but they could just email (or text message) their messages in and they would populate a slide in the slide show. I suspect there is a way to do this or an app for it, or a way to set it up. So the slide show would be presenting and as new messages come in you'd have a new slide. I don't need anything fancy with formats or fonts though that's nice to have. It could be Google Slides or Powerpoint, I have both.
Any advice would be appreciated. I am not all that great at coding APIs...

You're looking for at least 2 software here - email handler and presentation that can pick up data and create slides from the output of that. As I extremely doubt there's one app that will do it. For the 2nd part you're also actually probably better off with something like OBS Studio, which can easily work as "presentation", but is more open to automation thanks to e.g. Advanced Scene Switcher plugin.
